# Insert image into Word Doc, from Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

This code runs from Outlook and automates Word.

I want insert an image attachment from an Outlook mail item into a new Word doc. I'm saving the attachment and using the image file path in the code as below.

The code successfully creates a new Word doc, but the image is not inserted if I use the ActiveDocument object - no errors, just doesn't work.

If I create a new object (objActiveDoc) to replace ActiveDocument - to make it explicitly for Word, I get an error "Requested Object is not Available".

I tested in Word alone (with no Outlook involvement) and can successfully insert an image using ActiveDocument.

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim objActiveDoc As Document
Dim ImagePath As String

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add  'Create a new word Doc

Set objActiveDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument   'Do this as working from Outlook, not Word

ImagePath = "P:\OutlookImage\Image1.jpg"

    'With ActiveDocument '<------------ Does not work, no error
    With objActiveDoc   '<------------- ERROR Requested Object Not Available           
        .Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=ImagePath, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Left:=-5, _
        Top:=5, _
        Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
        Width:=111, _
        Height:=111
    End With
```

How do I get the image inserted into the Word doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have set objDoc to the new document that you have created to hold the image why are you then ignoring it and using ActiveDocument?

Get rid of objActiveDoc and just work with objDoc and your code will work exactly as you want it to, provided your images are always square.

If the images you want to add may not be square avoid setting the height and width otherwise you may distort the picture.

Comment: You’re right objDoc does work. I had tried this before but just now discovered that I apparently set the `objWord.Visible` property too early in the code (not in my example, sorry for that) so didn’t work.